# Lightbox video auto pop-up in page load

Tags: usability, lightbox

It is a good UX if we add an auto pop-up(Youtube Video) after page load?

What I have is a page called "The App", and the content of this page is all about the features, statistics, and etc.

I have a youtube video that has the app prototype presentation, and what I wanted is to make it the first object that users will noticed.

Should I display this as an auto pop-up(Youtube Video) after page load? or just put the video at the first entry content?

If I will be going to make the pop-up implementation, should I auto-play the video?

I know there are too many questions but those are somewhat related to the subject. Nevertheless any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's not considered bad UX I think you have the right idea.

A couple things to note:

- make sure that it doesn't auto play when the page loads, give the user an option instead to press play or to exit the window and display the content behind.
- ensure that if your video is being displayed over top of content that a use can easily exit, I may have repeated myself here but it's really important; you can't go wrong with medium sized X in the top right hand corner.  Another interaction trend to think about is to allow the window to be closed by clicking anywhere in the background.

The most important thing aside from what I've said is to just keep it simple. No distractions, no text, nothing but the video.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for not having the video autoplay. It is a pet peeve of mine.